# Convert Regexes

Tags: code-golf, regular-expression, conversion

Suppose you have existing regexes you wish to compile using one of the submissions to [Compile Regexes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7024/compile-regexes).

In as few characters as possible, write a program that:

- accepts an existing regex as input, as either (a) one line from standard input; or (b) one argument from the command line; or (c) the contents of a textbox in a dialog box; then
- converts the regex into one that works with the compiler (see "Equivalent constructs"); then
- prints the new regex either (a) on standard output; or (b) in a dialog box.

### Equivalent constructs

You can convert...

- ... the anchors `^` and `$` to the empty string. If `^` is not at the beginning (and/or if `$` is not at the end), prepend (and/or append) `.*`. (You may assume any `^` anchor is the first character of the regex and any `$` anchor is the last character of the regex.)
- ... non-capturing groups to normal groups; replace `(?:x)` with `(x)`.
- ... character classes; replace `.` with `[0-9A-Za-z]`, `\d` with `[0-9]`, and `\D` with `[A-Za-z]`. No character class will occur inside a bracket expression.
- ... bracket expressions to groups containing alternation. For example, `[0-9A-FZ]` can become `(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D|E|F|Z)`, and `[^0A-Za-z]` can become `(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)`.
- ... the plus operator: `+` to `{1,}`.
- ... braces (`x` is the nearest character or group to the left):

  - `x{m}` to m × `x`.
  - `x{m,}` to m × `x` followed by `x*`.
  - `x{m,n}` to m × `x` followed by either of:

    - (n-m) × `x?`
    - (n-m) × `(|x` then (n-m) × `)`
- ... the question mark operator: `x?` to `(|x)` or `(x|)`.

### Special rules

- You may assume all non-alphanumeric characters are metacharacters.
- Do not use general-purpose or Unicode algorithms to compress your code.
- Methods of input and output are implementation defined yet may not trivialize the solution.
- Using a special-purpose regex parsing library is prohibited. However, using one or more regexes as a tool for parsing the regex is OK (see below Scoring section).
- The input will never be longer than 1000 bytes.

### Scoring

Generally, the score is the number of characters in your submission. However, **you must double your score if you use a find-and-replace function and double it again if you use any regex or pattern matching function.** When writing your program, carefully consider whether to use regex and/or pattern matching functions, as using one just once quadruples your score.

### Test cases

Infinitely many valid outputs exist for each input case; thus, I have chosen a single example of possible output for each. The final test case is perhaps the trickiest.

#### Begins with "A"

```
 Input: ^A
Output: A(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*
```

- Valid: Abra, Absol, Aerodactyl, Aipom, Alakazam
- Invalid: abra, absol, Bayleef, Beedrill

#### Contains "sex"

```
 Input: sex
Output: (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*sex(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*
```

- Valid: partsexpress, sextet, middlesex
- Invalid: partSEXpress, SEXtet, middleSEX

#### Any decimal integer

```
 Input: ^\d+$
Output: (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*
```

- Valid: 0, 7, 51, 370, 1040, 65536, 007, 051, 0000370, 001040, 065536
- Invalid: (the empty string), football, 10NIS

#### Decimal integer without leading zeroes

```
 Input: ^(0|[1-9]\d*)$
Output: (0|(1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)*)
```

- Valid: 0, 7, 51, 370, 1040, 65536
- Invalid: 007, 051, 0000370, 001040, 065536, football, 10NIS

#### Lowercase Q without U word

```
 Input: ^[a-tv-z]*q[a-tv-z]*$
Output: (a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)*q(a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)*
```

- Valid: faqir, faqirs, qaid, qaids, qanat, qanats, qat, qats, qi, qindar, qindarka, qindars, qintar, qintars, qoph, qophs, qwerty, qwertys, sheqalim, sheqel, tranq, tranqs
- Invalid: Faqir, qAid, quid, liquefy

#### Ends in a vowel then three or more consonants

```
 Input: [AEIOUaeiou][^0-9AEIOUaeiou]{3,}$
Output: (0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*(A|E|I|O|U|a|e|i|o|u)(B|C|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z|b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)(B|C|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z|b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)(B|C|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z|b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)(B|C|D|F|G|H|J|K|L|M|N|P|Q|R|S|T|V|W|X|Y|Z|b|c|d|f|g|h|j|k|l|m|n|p|q|r|s|t|v|w|x|y|z)*
```

- Valid: Bouncy, bouncy, erhythm
- Invalid: Noisy, noisy, Dodge, rhythm

#### Exception to I before E, except after C

```
 Input: ^\D*([^Cc][Ee][Ii]|[Cc][Ii][Ee])\D*$
Output: (A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*((0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|A|B|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)(E|e)(I|i)|(C|c)(I|i)(E|e))(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r|s|t|u|v|w|x|y|z)*
```

- Valid (and incorrectly spelled): AIRFEILD, AIRfeild, eyepeice, reciept, veiwer, zeitgiest
- Valid (yet correctly spelled): forfeit, glacier, science, zeitgeist
- Invalid (and correctly spelled): AIRFIELD, AIRfield, eyepiece, receipt, viewer
- Invalid (yet incorrectly spelled): 6AIRFIELD, AIRFIELD0, forfiet, glaceir, sceince, zietgiest

#### U.S. amateur radio callsign

(Note that the FCC has [reserved some of these](http://wireless.fcc.gov/services/index.htm?job=call_signs_3&id=amateur&page=1#Call%20Sign%20Availability) (*e.g.* callsigns containing "SOS"), so not all of the matched callsigns could be legitimate callsigns used by U.S. amateur radio operators. 1x1 "special event" callsigns are not included.)

```
 Input: ^(?:[KNW]\d[A-Z]{2,3}|(?:A[A-L]|[KNW][A-Z])\d[A-Z]{1,2}|[KW][A-Z]\d[A-Z]{3})$
Output: ((K|N|W)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(|(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z))|(A(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L)|(K|N|W)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z))(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(|(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z))|(K|W)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z)(A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z))
```

- Valid: W1AW, AB0C, AB2MH, NZ9WA, K9DOG, KL5CD, KA2DOG, KN0WCW
- Invalid: WWVB, AB00, AM8ER, NZ99A, L9DOG, KNOWCW, KN0WCWW, kn0wcw

Comment: Should this be written as a program taking a line of input, a program taking a number of inputs, the function doing the actual work, or ?

Comment: @skibrianski: a complete program accepting a single regex on a single line; see update.

Answer (score 2):

## perl, <strike>1111</strike> 916 bytes

There is more golfing to do, but under 1000 bytes seemed like a good stopping point, especially as no one else has answered this question yet =)

```
@l=("A".."Z","a".."z");@h=(0..9,@l);sub g{join"|",@_}sub p{length$_[0]>1&&substr($_[0],0,1)ne"("?"($_[0])":$_[0]}sub e{$e=$_[0];for(split//,$_[1]){return if$i[$e++]ne$_}1}sub x{push@o,$l=p g @_}$w=c("^.*\$");sub N{++$n}sub I{$i[$n]}sub c{@i=split//,shift;$f=$t=0;shift@i,$f=1 if$i[0]eq"^";pop@i,$t=1 if$i[-1]eq"\$";@o=();for($n=0;$n<@i;N){if(e$n,"(?:"){push@o,"(";N;N}elsif(e$n,"."){x@h}elsif(e$n,"\\d"){x 0..9;N}elsif(e$n,"\\D"){x@l;N}elsif(e$n,"["){N;my($v,@c);$v=1,N if"^"eq I;while(I ne"]"){push@c,$i[$n+1]eq"-"?I..$i[$n+=2]:I;N}@c=grep{$d=$_;!grep{$_ eq$d}@c}@h if$v;x @c}elsif(e$n,"?"){splice@o,-1,1,"(|$l)"}elsif(e$n,"+"){$l=p$l;splice@o,-1,1,"$l$l*"}elsif(e$n,"{"){N;my($j,$k,$h);$j.=$i[$n++]until","eq I||"}"eq I;if(","eq I){$h=1;$k.=I until$i[N]eq"}"}$l=p$l;@r=$l x$j;push@r,defined$k?"(|$l)"x($k-$j):"$l*"if$h;splice@o,-1,1,@r}else{x I}}push@o,$w if!$t;join"",$f?@o:($w,@o)}while(<>){chomp;print c($_).$/}
```

And here's a still-pretty-obfuscated, but at-least-it's-indented version:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @let = ('A'..'Z','a'..'z');
my @chars = (0..9,@let);

sub g { join('|',@_) }
sub p { length $_[0] > 1 && substr($_[0],0,1) ne '(' ? "($_[0])" : $_[0] };

sub comp {
  my @i = split//,shift;
  my ($front_anchor, $tail_anchor);
  if($i[0] eq '^') { shift @i; $front_anchor=1 }
  if($i[-1] eq '$') { pop @i; $tail_anchor=1 }
  my @out;
  my $last;
  for(my $n=0;$n<@i;++$n) {
    if($i[$n] eq '(' && $i[$n+1] eq '?' && $i[$n+2] eq ':') {
      push @out, '(';
      $n+=2;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '.') {
      $last = g @chars;
      push @out, p $last;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '\\' && $i[$n+1] eq 'd') {
      $last = g 0..9;
      push @out, p $last;
      ++$n;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '\\' && $i[$n+1] eq 'D') {
      $last = g @let;
      push @out, p $last;
      ++$n;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '[') {
      ++$n;
      my $invert=0;
      if($i[$n] eq '^') {
        $invert=1;
        ++$n;
      }
      my @c;
      do {
        if($i[$n+1] eq '-') {
          push @c, $i[$n]..$i[$n+2];
          $n+=2;
        } else {
          push @c, $i[$n];
        }
        ++$n;
      } while($i[$n] ne ']');
      @c = grep { my $c=$_; !grep { $_ eq $c } @c } @chars if $invert;
      $last = g @c;
      push @out, p $last;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '?') {
      $last = "(|$last)";
      splice @out, -1, 1, $last;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '+') {
      $last = p $last;
      $last = "$last$last*";
      splice @out, -1, 1, $last;
    } elsif($i[$n] eq '{') {
      ++$n;
      my ($bm, $bn, $hc);
      $bm .= $i[$n++] until $i[$n] eq ',' || $i[$n] eq '}';
      if($i[$n] eq ',') {
        $hc=1;
        $bn .= $i[$n] until $i[++$n] eq '}';
      }
      my @r;
      push @r, p $last for 1..$bm;
      push @r, p($last).'*' if $hc && !defined $bn;
      if($hc && defined $bn) {
        my $y = $bn - $bm;
        push @r, '(|'.p($last).')' for 1..$y;
      }
      splice @out, -1, 1, @r;
      undef $last; #no nested quantifiers
    } else {
      $last = $i[$n];
      push @out, $last;
    }
  }
  @out = (comp('^.*$'),@out) unless $front_anchor;
  @out = (@out,comp('^.*$')) unless $tail_anchor;
  return wantarray?@out:join"",@out;
}

while(<>) {
  chomp;
  print comp($_)."\n";
}
```